# Decrement the column number in openpyxl using iter_rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I want to decrement the order of columns using openpyxl. I am searching for something in an order from right to left from the excel sheet.

```
for row in ws.iter_cols(min_row=1, min_col=10, max_col=1, max_row=10):
  for cell in row:
    <do something>
```

The result should be J1, I1, H1 etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can reverse the generator as the workaround:

```
rev_cols = reversed(list(ws.iter_cols(min_row=1, min_col=1, max_col=10, max_row=10)))
for col in rev_cols:
    for cell in col:
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks Yu-lin, it worked when I swapped the min_col and max_col values. It is serving my purpose now. :)

Comment: Thanks, I modified the answer -- I did not notice that :p